# Loading order jQuery UI and Oracle MapViewer in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, requirejs, oracle-map-viewer

I wanted to use jQuery UI Accordion in my module, but I always got *div.accordion is not a function* if I include Oracle MapViewer library. This library doesn't support AMD yet, so I defined its dependency in shim.
All libraries are loaded in the following order: jQuery UI, jQuery, (Oracle MapViewer). I thought jQuery should be loaded first, but that order works, except when I load Oracle MapViewer.

My HTML

```
<!--in head-->
<script src="lib/require.min.js" data-main="app"></script>

<!--in body-->
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.</div>
</div>
```

My app.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/jquery-1.12.3",
        "jquery-ui": "lib/jquery-ui",
        "oraclemaps": "lib/oraclemapsv2"
    },
    shim: {
        "oraclemaps": ['jquery']
    }
});

require(['oraclemaps', 'jquery-ui'], function ()
{
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Any idea how to use the Oracle MapViewer library in RequireJS? I use jQuery 1.12.3 and jQuery UI 1.11.4 (all components).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oraclemaps includes jQuery, so we could opt to use their version. The configuration would be like this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery-ui": "lib/jquery-ui.min",
        "oraclemaps": "lib/oraclemapsv2"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery-ui": ["oraclemaps"]
    }
});

require(["jquery-ui"], function ()
{
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you shim section of the first example like this:

```
shim: {
    "jquery-ui": {
        export:"$" ,
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
```

Or update to the latest jQuery-ui version which at last supports AMD loading.

Comment: Still got error. I use the latest stable version and it supports AMD (there's _if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd )_ in the source code)

Comment: Adding the `export` won't make any difference, and the OP is using 1.11.4, which does have AMD support (support was added in 1.11.0).

Comment: Have you checked via browser console if the modules are loaded or requested at all?

Comment: Yes, both scripts are on the head section of the HTML.